# Why doesn't data return when I use Sim808 http request

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, http

Why is it that when i use this code for http request on DFRobot_sim808 , I get 'fetch over' message, that means that no data is being returned?

char strings:

```c
char http_cmd[] = " HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        "Host: 5ac80719.ngrok.io\r\n"
                        "\r\n";
char first[] = "GET /index.php?lat=";

char requestion[100];
```

functions to join them:

```c
void setup() {
  float lat = 32.685362, lon = 48.411512;
  char char_coor[10];

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

// Set Http Cmd
  strcpy(requestion,first);
// For Convert latitude float to char
  dtostrf(lat, 4, 6, char_coor);  
  strcat(requestion,char_coor);
// For Convert longitude float to char
  dtostrf(lon, 4, 6, char_coor);
  strcat(requestion,"&long=");
  strcat(requestion,char_coor);
  strcat(requestion,http_cmd);

.
.
.
```

and fetching:

```c
sim808.send(requestion, strlen(requestion)-1);
  while (true) {
      int ret = sim808.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
      if (ret <= 0){
          Serial.println("fetch over...");
          break; 
      }

/*
The program stops at above
*/

      buffer[ret] = '\0';
      Serial.print("Recv: ");
      Serial.print(ret);
      Serial.print(" bytes: ");
      Serial.println(buffer);
      break;
  }
```

thanks

Comment: OK i mean why no data returned??

Comment: perhaps the device is not connected to the internet ... it is your job to do basic troubleshooting and update your question with a description of what you already tried

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see is the `while` loop has a `break` statement in it that "exits" the `while` loop before printing the data. Removing that `break` and printing the data out where the `break` "was" may help. Here's an example of what I'm trying to say:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop(){

  while(true){
    int ret = 0;
    if(ret <= 0){
      Serial.println("fetch over...");
      // Print out the received data here...
      Serial.print("Recv: ");
      Serial.print(ret);
      break;
    }
  }

}
```